# How do I add and remove a class in JQuery to toggle a scroll bar on the body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struglling to add and remove a class in order to hide then show the scroll abr on the body tag. I have the follwoing code so far.

```
<label class="hamburger" for="sidebarToggler" id="menuToggle"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggler" name="sidebar" value=""> 

$("#menuToggle").click(function () {
    if ($('#menuToggle').hasClass('close-menu')) {
        $('body').removeClass('hide-scroll');
    }
    else {
        $('body').addClass('hide-scroll');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the  .  on this line: `if ($('#menuToggle').hasClass('.close-menu')) {` and change it to `if ($('#menuToggle').hasClass('close-menu')) {`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here that could be going wrong.

**Ensure you have a proper jQuery Reference and "Ready" Function**

You need to ensure that any jQuery code that you are writing actually can access a reference to the jQuery library and that the code itself is wrapped in a "ready" function like the one seen below to ensure it is only called after jQuery is loaded :

```
<!-- Place your jQuery Reference here (or somewhere above here) -->
<script>
   // Document ready function
   $(function(){
      $("#menuToggle").click(function () {
         if ($('#menuToggle').hasClass('.close-menu')) {
            $('body').removeClass('hide-scroll');
        }
        else{
            $('body').addClass('hide-scroll');
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```

**Ensure your markup is correct**

Currently you are missing a closing `>` for your `<label>` element which can cause issues if you are targeting things with jQuery (like causing your `click` event to not be picked up) :

```
<label class="hamburger" for="sidebarToggler" id="menuToggle"></label>
```

or if you wanted to wrap your checkbox within it, simply handle it that way :

```
<label class="hamburger" for="sidebarToggler" id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggler" name="sidebar" value="">
</label>
```

**Simplify your code using the `toggleClass()` function**

Your code could be slightly simplified to toggle the class you are targeting by using the `toggleClass()` function as follows :

```
$("#menuToggle").click(function () {
     // Explicitly toggle your class on this element
     $(this).toggleClass('close-menu');
     // Notice that you don't need the leading '.' when using the hasClass
     // function
     $('body').toggleClass('hide-scroll',$(this).hasClass('close-menu'));
});
```

So a [complete example](http://jsbin.com/cekapu/edit?html,css,output) might look like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Scroll Hide Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label class="hamburger" for="sidebarToggler" id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggler" name="sidebar" value="">
  </label>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function(){
          $("#menuToggle").click(function () {

              $(this).toggleClass('close-menu');
              // Notice that you don't need the leading '.' when using the hasClass
              // function
              $('body').toggleClass('hide-scroll',$(this).hasClass('close-menu'));
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. The closing label was a typo on here :) I tryed the new JQuery but it doesnt add the class of hide-scroll now ?

Comment: I've updated the code accordingly. Basically whenever you click event occurs, you need to toggle the `close-menu` class on the triggering element so that it can then be used to toggle your other class.

Comment: Thank you very very much :)